# Firebase realtime database not working on specific networks

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

My code for fetching data from realtimedb

```
Log.d("checkFlow","reached here:requesting data")
Firebase.database.getReference("serverloc").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("checkFlow","reached here:got the data")
        startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, Home::class.java))
        finish()
    }
})
```

when I run this application using my mobile data

```
D/checkFlow: reached here:requesting data
```

when I use my other network

```
D/checkFlow: reached here:requesting data
D/checkFlow: reached here:got the data
```

I tried with other devices too, same results. Also many users of my application are saying the same thing too!

EDIT:
[image: Data structure]

Comment: you log so it's will show message on any device, really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh I'm saying that when I use mobile data, the application cannot fetch the data from the firebase realtime database. But when I use my wifi network, it works fine.